# JPA null value in column "header_id" of relation "invoice" violates not-null constraint with PostgresSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Getting below Error while saving data

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "header_id" of relation "invoice" violates not-null constraint
> Detail: Failing row contains (...null).

**Header**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "header")
public class Header implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3363186434410305269L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "header_id")
    private Long headerId;

    @Column(name = "submitted_by", length = 17)
    private String submittedBy;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "header", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Builder.Default
    private List<Invoice> invoices = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**Invoice**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice")
public class Invoice implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "invoice_id")
    private Long invoiceId;

    @Column(name = "serial_no")
    private Integer serialNo;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "header_id", nullable = false)
    private Header header;
}
```

Please help me to solve the error.

Comment: While you are trying to inserting data in `invoice` table, You didn't get proper reference from `header` table. At that time your foreign key is trying to store as `null` then error is coming. Can you show me your `service` and `controller` code?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your `headerId` can be null because you use "Long" as type, wich is a good practice, but you should remove `nullable = false` inside `Invoice.java`.
Put `nullable = false` inside your database rules
If this problem does not come from there, check that the headerId of your Header class is not null when you create the object that you want to save in the database